# How do I change background for the thumb with styled components?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, styled-components

I'm trying to change the background color for the thumb with styled-components for `react`, but I do not know how, cant seem to get it. My styled-components look like this:

```
 const InputVolume = styled.input`
           ::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
                width: 100%;
                height: 4px;
                cursor: pointer;
                box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
                background-color: #FFFFFF;
                border-radius: 25px;
                border: 0px solid #000101;
            };
            &:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
                background: #D78E91;
            };
            ::-webkit-slider-thumb {
                background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    `;
```

Answer (score 0):

Word of warning: the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-slider-thumb) recommend against using this in production.

It looks like you're just missing setting some `appearance: none` properties and then adding a few more to specify things like height and width. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-stallman-tz65t?file=/src/App.js:91-720) is a working example of the snippet below.

Also, it looks like you have some typos in your styles. You've got a border set to 0px, same with your box shadow, and a border radius that only needs to be 2px, not 25px (based on the height and what I'm assuming you're trying to do with it).

```
const InputVolume = styled.input`
  appearance: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  ::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    height: 4px;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    pointer-events: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #000101;
  }
  &:focus {
    outline: none;
  }
  &:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background: #d78e91;
  }
  &::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    appearance: none;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-top: -6px;
    border: 1px solid #777;
  }
`;
```